# Convert an array with index and value into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as key => value pair such as:

```
$array = [ 10 => 'Windows', 12 => 'Keyboard', 15 => 'Monitor' ];
```

What I would like to achieve without using any foreach or loops the following:

```
$converted = [ 
  0 => [ 'id' => 10, 'name' => 'Windows'],
  1 => [ 'id' => 12, 'name' => 'Keyboard'],
  2 => [ 'id' => 15, 'name' => 'Monitor']
];
```

Here they indices in new array doesn't matter. Any tips??

Comment: _"without using any foreach or loops"_ - Why?

Comment: I don't see any solution without a loop... even an `array_map` will loop internally

Comment: Well its not really a requirement but I am looking for any single liner solution if that is possible. Otherwise no harm in using foreach

Comment: Well, you can write _anything_ in a single line. :D But there is no built-in function for this, so you won't get much more compact than a `foreach` anyway.

Comment: What's the use-case? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

No `foreach` and no loop, but now there is a closure:

```
$result = array_map(function ($id, $name) {
    return [
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name
    ];
}, array_keys($array), array_values($array));
```

Even if there was a PHP function that did this exactly, it would be using a loop internally.

```
function do_what_ghazanfar_mir_wants(array $array) {
    return array_map(function ($id, $name) {
        return [
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name
        ];
    }, array_keys($array), array_values($array));
}
```

And the single liner is:

```
$result = do_what_ghazanfar_mir_wants($array);
```

And the `foreach` approach for comparison:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($array as $id => $name) {
    $res[] = [ 'id' => $id, 'name' => $name ];
}
```

Comment: You are a star. This what I am looking for, the combination of multiple array functions.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir - I think that a `foreach` solution, written in a single line, would be about the same length.

Comment: @SeanBright - Yup, I just tried. This one is 113 chars in one line without whitespace. A foreach loop with the same variable names is 76 chars.

Comment: Frankly, I find the `foreach` cleaner and more readable in this case.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir - Sorry, `foreach` wins. :)

Comment: Agreed guys - the performance or other factors are really not in question at this point. I was interested in knowing if array functions can achieve this at all

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it really short then [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) will do it in one line:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) { $value = ['id' => $key, 'name' => $value]; });
```

See https://3v4l.org/OEohi

But I think a foreach loop is probably going to be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), Just pass the keys `array_keys($array)` and values `$array` as the parameter of your `array_map()`

```
<?php
$array = [ 10 => 'Windows', 12 => 'Keyboard', 15 => 'Monitor' ]; 
function map_by_key($m, $n)
{
    return(array('id' => $m, 'name'=>$n));
}

$output = array_map("map_by_key", array_keys($array),$array);
print '<pre>';
print_r($output);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/iTVSm